# How can I solve logstash error during installation time?

Tags: logstash

I am using JDK 15 and trying to install logstash. But when I use the command with configuration file I am getting this error -

> "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal
> exception has occurred. Program will exit."

I have added an image of the error below. Please help me to solve the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Logstash does not support Java 15 yet, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/12243) about it, but you won't be able to use Java 15 to run logstash until support is available.

You will need to use another Java version, currently logstash [supports](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html#ls-jvm) Java 8, Java 11 or Java 14.

You can also unset the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and logstash will use its bundled java, which is AdoptOpenJDK 11.